# Преобразование Date( )

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, дата, new

Пытаюсь разобраться в Js + React. Делаю первые шаги.

Хочу написать  таймер обратного отсчёта даты. Предположил, что дату буду вводить в админке, поэтому в функцию она будет попадать в виде строки. По факту, после вычислений получаю интересную историю.
Помещаю в HTML:

```html
<span id='days' className='days_num'>{getTimeRemaiing()}</span>
```

И браузер говорит = `NaN`, в то время как консоль утверждает, что это `number`, то есть число. Ошибок  консоль не выдаёт, но и `NaN` вместо  красивых циферок на странице  не хочется видеть.  Функция находится в функциональном компоненте.

```js
const Main = function(){

    const deadline = '2024-05-09';

    function getTimeRemaiing(endtime){
        
        const t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse( new Date()),
            days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 *24));
            console.log(typeof(days))

        return days
    }
```

Comment: Технически NaN это число. А фактически, зачем пытаться парсить результат new Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dateString = "2024-05-09";

const [year, month, day] = dateString.split("-");

const countDownDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();

const x = setInterval(() => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const distance = countDownDate - now;
    const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${days} суток, ${hours} часов, ${minutes} минут`;

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Время истекло!";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#countdown {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Предлагаю такой пример таймера обратного отсчета даты

Comment: Прошу прощения , а деструктуризацию в данном коде   нет возможности  использовать ? Это  из-за того что dateParts  превращается в массив ?

Comment: Исправил код с использованием деструктуризации массива

Comment: @Azimut на всякий случай напомню про существование часовых поясов. Так что в Москве и в Хабаровске таймер будет показывать разное время.

Comment: Да сейчас выглядит компактней.   В переменную countDownDate попадает временная  метка где месяц  указан как month -1 . Почему  -1 ?

Comment: При создании объекта Date в JavaScript месяцы начинаются с 0 (январь) и заканчиваются 11 (декабрь). Поэтому, чтобы использовать обычные значения месяцев (1-12), нужно вычесть 1 при указании месяца в объекте Date. То есть когда мы делаем -1 то нумерация месяца начинается не с нуля, а с единицы

Comment: Да. Понятно. Как то я этот момент  упустил.  Ведь действительно в програмировании  счёт с нуля ))  Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ !

Comment: Рад был помочь!)))